# Openshift installation playbook failing

Tags: redhat, centos7, ansible, ansible-playbook, openshift-origin

I'm trying to install 2-node cluster with origin version 3.10 (one master, one node). Playbook fails on task

> openshift_control_plane : Wait for control plane pods to appear

```
Initialization              : Complete (0:00:35)
Health Check                : Complete (0:00:41)
Node Bootstrap Preparation  : Complete (0:01:39)
etcd Install                : Complete (0:00:31)
Master Install              : In Progress (0:18:40)
    This phase can be restarted by running: playbooks/openshift-master/config.yml


Failure summary:


  1. Hosts:    openshift-master.itandwisdom.com
     Play:     Configure masters
     Task:     Report control plane errors
     Message:  Control plane pods didn't come up
```

My ansible version is ansible 2.6.5, openshift-ansible version is 3.10.82-1 
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

This situation also happens with version 3.11

```
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd

[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
openshift_disable_check=disk_availability,memory_availability,docker_storage
openshift_release="3.10.0"
openshift_image_tag="v3.10.0"
openshift_pkg_version="-3.10.0"

openshift_deployment_type=origin
[masters]
openshift-master.itandwisdom.com openshift_public_ip=185.136.232.200 openshift_public_hostname=openshift-master.itandwisdom.com

[etcd]
openshift-node.itandwisdom.com openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute' openshift_public_ip=185.136.233.130 openshift_public_hostname=openshift-node.itandwisdom.com

[nodes]
openshift-master.itandwisdom.com openshift_public_ip=185.136.232.200 openshift_public_hostname=openshift-master.itandwisdom.com openshift_schedulable=true openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master-infra'
openshift-node.itandwisdom.com openshift_public_ip=185.136.233.130 openshift_public_hostname=openshift-node.itandwisdom.com openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute'
```

[Output of ansible-playbook](https://gist.github.com/K-DOT/2deb5590e781735ac3083693f0449e31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I had two different issues:

- Hostname should match FQDN (hostname == hostname -f)
  https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/21285
- Docker exec command bug
  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1655214

More info: https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/10798

Hope it will help somebody.